# How many of each function exists between each set

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have these functions:

(a) Surjections from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$

(b) Injections from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$

(c) Bijections from the set $\{\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Q}, 0\} \to \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R^2}, π\}$

(d) Surjections from the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ to the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$?

And I was wondering how many of each type of function exists between the given sets.

But I am confused about how to work these out? For the first one I thought there would be the same amount of functions as the real numbers, for the second one I thought there would be the same amount of functions as the natural numbers. The third one I though would be zero as there are no true bijections between each? And finally I thought 36 as $1\to1$, $2\to2$, $3\to3$ and $4\to\{1,2,3\}$. Which has $6$ options and can be repeated three times so $6*3!=36$?

If anyone could help me understand these it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a, it is the same as the number of functions $\Bbb{ R \to N}$.  You can just say the naturals in $\Bbb R$ go to the same number, which ensures a surjection.  Now you still have $\mathfrak c$ numbers to assign values to, which is the same as all the reals.

For b, there are too many reals to avoid a collision, so there are no injections.

For c, the elements of the sets do not matter, just how many there are.  How many elements are in each set?

For d, count the number of functions and subtract those that are not surjections.  You will need inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Oh thank you I understand! How would you go about doing D?

Comment: A function is not a surjection if the image is only one or two numbers, so compute the number of functions that have those images.  You can read Wikipedia on inclusion-exclusion or search this site